# How set timeout of query in joomla?

Tags: php, joomla

I use joomla connect to postgresql:

```
$db = JFactory::getDBO();
$db->setQuery($query);
$db->query();        
$object = $db->loadAssocList();
```

Default timeout=30s. I want set timeout =120.
How set timeout of query? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use the standard php function

> set_time_limit(120);

Answer (score 2):

```
set_time_limit
```

Set the number of seconds a script is allowed to run. If this is reached, the script returns a fatal error. The default limit is 30 seconds or, if it exists, the `max_execution_time` value defined in the php.ini.

When called, `set_time_limit()` restarts the timeout counter from zero. In other words, if the timeout is the default 30 seconds, and 25 seconds into script execution a call such as `set_time_limit(20)` is made, the script will run for a total of 45 seconds before timing out.